# pip3 broken / can't install httpie

Tags: pi-b+, pip

I'm running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 8` on a Pi Model B Plus Rev 1.2 (according to `cat /proc/cpuinfo`)

I have `python3-pip` installed. I tried the following (with & without `sudo`):

```
pip3 install httpie
```

But I get errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'
```

I also get the same errors if I try `pip3 install --upgrade pip3`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: "*Raspbian GNU/Linux 8*" (Jessie) not supported.

Comment: Ah ok. When I'm feeling brave I'll try to update it. Thx. (where did you quote that from?)